# Android Studio: Failed to find: 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build an app in Android Studio with the support library but I get the following error when adding the dependency for the support library:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sample.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

}
```

I have downloaded the support library via the sdk manager.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. The Android support repository was missing. After installing and restarting Android Studio it worked.

Comment: Was my problem indeed. More on the support library here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Android Studio, then as an addition to changing the build.gradle file manually, you can also lookup the dependency via the library dependencies under the Project Structure menu item.

[image: Find where com.android.support is]

Double clicking that dependency will generate this line in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
}
```

And also, if you are wondering what this library is about, it's described at the developer pages at developer.android.com; [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: I installed the android support repository. Then I tried to add the support library by editing `build.gradle` as described in Android developer guide and it didn't work. Your method fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My Android Studio version is 1.1. I select `tools`->`Android`->`SDK Manager`, check the **Android Support Library** then click `Install packages`, solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was as simple as running `Build`:`Make Project`.  No amount of gradle syncing or clearing caches would do it.  Of course, that required getting my project into a state where it would build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add Google Maven repository.

It shows as part of the error in Android Studio and only needed to click on it to add itself.

Then Gradle built the project on its own.

Answer (score -1):

Following the instruction here helped me. For whatever reason when I had to reinstall the latest version of android studio the initial download of the extras section android support library failed. I simply retried it. Followed the steps mentioned and verified it was added to the build.gradle file and did a rebuild project and good to go.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: This is the same link as I already posted in my answer, just a different sub menu item...

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. It's still basically a copy of an existing answer.