# Error : Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported a project in Android Studio that was built in it. I require v4 and v7 library in the project. This is how my build.gradle looks like

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.sdk'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
}
```

When I sync with gradle then it always gives error message

> Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+ & Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+

[image]

[image]

Please support & thanks in advance.

Comment: look into this [so post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24607741/3326331)

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Yes I tried that also

Comment: You could use `19.1.0` instead of `20.0.+` in both `compile` statements. Beyond that, make sure that you are up to date in your SDK Manager, particularly ensuring that you have the "Android Repository" installed.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see I added screenshot

Comment: The "Android Repository" is in the "Extras" area, further down the SDK Manager tree.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see I added second screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, it's "Android Support Repository" that you need to install, and presently you do not have it installed.

Comment: In my situation I had the Android Support Library installed, but did not have the Android Support Repository.  It takes both.  Thanks for your posting I figured this out.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `Android` support repository was missing,So go to `Android SDK`, install the `Android Support Repository` and `Android Support Library`.
Also you can use the following

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
```

Answer (score 12):

Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the Android Support Repository item instead.

see [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download).

Answer (score 4):

From Android Studio go to: Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager

Select and install "Extras|Android Support Repository"

Answer (score 1):

add maven to your gradle file (project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

and use this gradle wrapper:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and downgrade to gradle plugin to be 2.3.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```