# Android: Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

I add this library in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.appeaser.sublimepickerlibrary:sublimepickerlibrary:2.0.0'
```

I've already these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile "com.android.support:design:23.+"
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
```

Since, I've added SublimePicker library, I add this error:

Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
Required by:
    Android:app:unspecified

Could you help me guys ?

Comment: I have founded this possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/a/41088967/2666042

Answer (score 20):

You **have to update** the SDK Manager.

[image]

In any case you **should avoid the use of the** `+` in your dependendencies.
Using the `+` you will not able to replicate the build since you don't know which dependencies you are using.

Use:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: Gabriele, it's not this problem. My SDK has been updated with 23.2.1 version. The problem is when I add the SublimePicker library; without that the build is fine!

Comment: @anthony It is quite strange. Have you tried to remove that dependencies using the 23.2.1 of support libraries (without the +) ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same behavior. You can try with a template project, just try to build and you will have this problem.

Comment: Did that. Did not help. Maven downloaded the correct version itself. Gradle just sucks.

Comment: And not it works. Also for no apparent reason. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

After clicking “yes” to another obscure suggestion from IntelliJ IDEA the following change was made:

```
>git diff gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
diff --git a/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties b/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
index b2d6236..1966ba0 100644
--- a/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
+++ b/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-#Mon Jan 11 11:12:07 CET 2016
+#Sat Mar 26 12:30:43 CET 2016
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Now it works. Why? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because of the question's title, **Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1**. That means I haven't added any library to my gradle file, just wanted to build an existing project.

After going through quite a few answers on questions with very similar titles, I finally found a solution that worked for me on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/4enuzs/cant_compile_for_android_extremely_frustrated/), which basically says, within the context of the Android SDK Manager:

> I had to install the Android Support Repository, and remove all the google options from extras (google play services, google repository etc.) and I got my first successful build!

Since I didn't have any of the Google extras installed anyway, I just needed to add the Android Support Repository 40.  Note that I didn't try to uninstall the (apparently now obsolete) Android Support Library 23.2.1, but that would certainly be an interesting experiment at this point... though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25890218/897968) suggests it is required anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. On your build.gradle file add the next:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```