# Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1

Tags: react-native

When using react-native 0.28 and above (0.29, 0.30-rc), I get the following error when executing `react-native run-android` in  a fresh `react-native init app` project.

```
Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
```

I installed the newest android studio and even installed the obsolete library manually.

[image: installed]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complete Tonithy's answer - the `.jar` may not be enough, you need to copy two whole directories, otherwise gradle will complain for the missing `.aar`. In this case, I think that those were installed by Android Studio:
`{USER}/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/`

And don't forget the dependency:
`{USER}/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.1/`

I had exactly the same problem while upgrading to `react-native 0.30`, that solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers! In the end I had to copy both folder `support-v4/23.2.1` and `support-annotations/23.2.1` as you said @Simon. Those are my two command: `cp -r ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1 /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4
;
cp -r ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.1 /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations
`

Answer (score 5):

Google seems to have stopped including a version of each support library without sources/javadoc/etc and React is looking for this specific file. Assuming you manually installed the obsolete version, it will be in `{YOUR_ANDROID_LOCATION}/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` Your best bet is to manually copy it in:

```
cp {YOUR_ANDROID_LOCATION}/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar {YOUR_ANDROID_LOCATION}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
```

---

This a React Native (version and probably OSX specific bug), it will probably be fixed soon. For posterity, your full error was something like this, looking for support in all the wrong places:

```
OsagieTheGreat-MBA:somereactapp osagiethegreat$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/Documents/somereactapp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/Documents/somereactapp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         SomeReactApp:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
         SomeReactApp:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.29.0 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/Documents/somereactapp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/osagiethegreat/Documents/somereactapp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/Android Dev/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         SomeReactApp:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.29.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.11.0
         SomeReactApp:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.29.0 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.11.0
         SomeReactApp:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.29.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.11.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.838 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error, after installing Android Support Library the error has gone. 
Install Android Support Library from Extras

[image]

Comment: This works for me, I just update the Android Support Repository and it's going well.

Answer (score 1):

First solution could be adding this

```
    compile 'com.android.tools:sdklib:23.2.1'
```

to the next file

> android/app/build.gradle

Second solution is installing **Android Support Repository**

Answer (score 0):

To Complete Tonithy's and Simon's answer, yes the jar itself was not enough, all the files of two directories -
    `extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/` and
   `extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.1/` are needed. On my Windows PC, I couldn't find files of these directories anywhere.

So what I did was, I downloaded these folders from [googlesource](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/)

**1. [support/support-annotations/23.2.1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.1)**

Download tgz of above folder and extract the files into `{YOUR_ANDROID_LOCATION}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.2.1/`

**2. [support/support-v4/23.2.1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/20a4bd598cf3ba8434311156ce94c110a0024fe7/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/)**

Download tgz of above folder and extract the files into `{YOUR_ANDROID_LOCATION}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/`

Now go to your command propmt or terminal and run `react-native run-android`

Hope it save someone few hours!!