# React-native error when running on android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to react-native, and I'm trying to get the test app up and running on my phone. At first, I was getting an error where it couldn't find the support library v4 (23.2.1), so I followed the advice on another stackoverflow post ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352754/could-not-find-com-android-supportsupport-v423-2-1)) and copied `android-support-v4.jar` over from `extras/android/support/v4/` to `extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/` and renamed it to `support-v4-23.2.1.jar`. Now I'm getting this error:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1).
> >       Searched in the following locations:
> >
> > > file:/C:/Users/Ritvik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.aar

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo when you renamed the file. You renamed the file to `support-v4-23.2.1.aar`.

Look at the extension, that should be `jar` not `aar`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've renamed the file to .jar, not .aar. .aar appears to be the missing file.