# Use Android Studio with existing Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

**NOTICE: I found other questions and answers about the same issue, but the answers are for older versions of Android Studio, and I want confirmation if it still can work for the latest version of Android Studio (*2.2.3.0 which was released on December 6, 2016*)**

I'm new to the Android development and I selected the IDE to use wrongly and before thinking and knowing which IDE to use.

So after this mistake, I must use Android Studio now to use the GRADLE libraries as Eclipse doesn't officialy support them (because Eclipse is now discontinued).

The Android Studio is 1.63 GB (including the Android SDK), while Android Studio is 417 MB (without the Android SDK).

I have Android SDK Tools R25.2.3 ( latest ) already downloaded, so I don't want to download the whole Studio + The Android SDK again.

Is it possible to download the Android Studio without the SDK, then link the SDK to the Studio manually?

I'd be very thankful if someone could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible , Studio and SDK can been seen as separate components and they can be linked by providing SDK path in the studio IDE or you can configure you SDK path thorough the setting menu shown at the start screen of android studio.

You can download the standalone IDE through [Official Android Studio site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable).

Note : http://tools.android.com/ has dropped the support of providing separate SDK and IDE components but still IDE can be downloaded individually from [Android Official Download Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Steps to configure after download

1.) Download and Extract the IDE

2.) Find studio or studio64 exe and run the appropriate one in your OS

3.) When you start your studio , it will probably ask for `SDK` location through a prompt screen and provide the location and hit next and next , eventually it will show you a little process for update window and show you finish screen (Must follow the note below)

3.a) If there was no prompt screen shown then you can configure the `SDK` path using the setting option on the Splash screen of android studio

3.b) It's possible that when you open an old studio project and `SDK`is still not configured because every project has it's own setting so again you can see the link in error/log window as `configure SDK` and just click the link and provide path

Note : Disable internet before configuring you studio otherwise it will look for Updates

Helpful points to possible issue

- For old project , replace the old dependencies with the one you have in project structure [link for Visual representation of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607741/android-studio-failed-to-find-com-android-supportsupport-v419-1-0)
- Replace the gradle version with the one supported by your new studio and do the same if any other tool is not found.

Comment: Oh, so it prompt to select the SDK path on the first start of "Android Studio (without Android SDK)" ?

Comment: @protld yes and make sure you are not connected to internet otherwise it will try to download the things by prompting screen to look for updates , let me add things to my answer for more details about this

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @protld i like this way too , especially helpful to many guys who don't have hi-speed or unlimited speed net connection most of the time

Comment: That's my same reason too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. The Android Studio IDE prompts you to specify the path containing the Android SDK tools, if it doesn't detect the SDK automatically.