# Android SDK not being installed on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Based on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332532/use-android-studio-with-existing-android-sdk-tools) - I downloaded Android Studio (without the SDK) 2.2.3.0 from this link (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.2.3.0/android-studio-ide-145.3537739-windows.exe).

Then I downloaded the Android SDK from this link (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip).

I extracted the Android SDK to "C:\androidsdk" , and now the "androidsdk" folder contains a folder called "tools". and inside this "tools" there's a lot of files.

When I open Android Studio, it already download the SDK. So I disconnect the internet and open Android Studio again. Now I choose the SDK path manually, which is "C:\androidsdk" .. here is the problem, I get:

> Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK
>   installation.

So, I selected the path as "C:\androidsdk\tools" instead of that and I get the same problem.

Comment: Hey @protld I am facing a similar issue. Can you please indicate which of the answers below solved your problem? Accepting that answer will be helpful for everyone on SO

Answer (score 8):

I have found a solution which involve changing the default of android studio. Create an empty folder namely 'platforms' in your downloaded SDK Go to Configure->project setting ->Specify path to your SDK.   Link is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/989007/sdk-is-missing-error-android-studio

This has worked for me using latest downloaded SDK.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooo much!

Comment: This simple answer just saved me from lots of headaches, I was struggling for 1 hour make it work in android studio.

Comment: You Saved My Life :)

Answer (score 6):

I get problem like this. Just create emprty folder **platforms** inside **SDK** and click next button. It solved my problem :)

Comment: There's already mention of that in one of the existing answers.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yeah I know, but existing answers not understandable(it seems to me)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I created a new folder, platform, at 'C:\Android\sdk\platform' and clicked next but it didn't install. I've downloaded the command line tools only and extracted the contents to 'C:\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest'. I tried the reasonable folders that might work as the "Android SDK Location" but says "Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to download the Android Studio version that already includes the SDK? I'm not sure, but I think you're downloading a file for developers that don't use Android Studio. You should download [this file](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.2.3.0/android-studio-bundle-145.3537739-windows.exe) (android-studio-bundle-145.3537739-windows.exe) instead. ;w;

Comment: In my last question, some members already said it's possible to download everything standalone. and I did that because my internet is slow,

Comment: Oh, I see. Well.. you can download the sdk separately from another website. I think techspot website has a download page just for the sdk. ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, straight from google, which is where you will want to download if your company firewall blocks other sources,  [Release 1.6 r1 September 2009](https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases?hl=en) is the latest SDK they have.

You can then go to *Settings > System Settings > Android SDK*

[image]

Give the required Android SDK Location.

[image]

**Wait until the Next button is enabled.**

Now you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The link you quote is the link to SDK tools, not to the complete SDK. You need to put this tools folder into an existing SDK (given that the tools version supports the SDK version).

You need an SDK first (replace tools folder there or, much better, use SDK Manager.exe provided with the SDK, to update tools to the desired version).

AFAIK, for standalone SDK 25 there is not official standalone download link (for 24 there was). Install studio, use SDK manager from there (or run as exe in SDK installed with Studio), then go to SDK folder and grab the complete SDK after update if you need it separately for offline installation. You can replace tools directly in this folder or in copy, but better use the SDK manager.

Note there are various non-official sites for downloading offline SDK separately, you can easily google for them but it is the question of how much do you trust these sites to download executables. This is definitely a questionable path in an enterprise environment. I'm not sure why can't you just download the studio and install with SDK. If you need SDK later in other installations, install, configure and update, grab the SDK folder and uninstall.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-an-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was discovered, however it's not a solution but you have to do it if you want to use Android Studio.

---

If you want a solution, then you have to use a bit older version of Android SDK which is 24.4.1, and it can be downloaded from some sites like **Techspot** and **FileHippo**, [here](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html) or [here](http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/).

It's available as .EXE file, just open the installer and continue with the installation then Android Studio should automatically detect it.

---

If you want the latest version of the Android SDK for Android Studio, then you must download the "Android Studio (including the Android SDK)" from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html .

NOTICE: The last solution isn't a solution, but it's the Android Studio with the Android SDK. and both of them are in one 1 .EXE, you just have to open it and you're ready now.