# android studio v3.2.1 shows sdk is missing when it runs

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I downloaded installer of *"android studio v3.2.1"* for *"windows 10 64bit"* from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) site.

its absolute url is this:
[android-studio-ide-173.4720617-windows.exe](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.1.2.0/android-studio-ide-173.4720617-windows.exe)

I installed it and then run it and it showed me this error in a window:

> your android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted.

that window had two buttons: 1- open sdk manager | 2- cancel

I clicked on *"open sdk manager"* button and a window called *"Default Settings"* was opened:

[image: Default Settings window]

in *"Android SDK"* section there was an empty path box called *"android sdk location"*. I clicked on *"Edit"* label in front of that empty path box and it opened another window called *"SDK setup"*

[image]

in section *"Android SDK Location"* there was a path box with this default path:

> C:\Users\saeid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

but in *"Local"* folder there was not any folder called *"Android"*.

I maked another folder in another path:

> D:\android_sdk

and put this address in the path box and clicked on *"Next"* button and after that android studio downloaded some packages and files in that path. at the end, below image was contents of this path:

[image]

after that when I want to make a new project it gives me the *"sdk missing"* error again !!

and path box of *"android sdk location"* in *"default settings"* window in *"android sdk"* section is empty yet !!

and when I put *"D:\android_sdk"* address in path box of *"android sdk location"* in *"sdk setup"* window it shows me this error:

> Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to existing SDK
> location

and then when I click on *"Next"* button in next window it shows me this message:

> Nothing to do!
>
> Android SDK is up to date.

I am confused and don't know what must I do ?!!

Comment: This shows you where you can download your SDK and load it into your Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072897/4977531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time later I started the android studio again from the first and it started to download another platform packages and then problem solved !!