# Android SDK is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

First i downloaded Android studio and run it it says that SDK is missing.But at the same time it says that it is installed.And this box is uncheckable  [image: But at the same time it says that it is installed]

And shows the directory for SDK that not exist. I looked for that file in whole my computer but didn't find that. So i downloaded SDK file manually and saved that in that default directory as in above picture. Still no result.And If i press next here this will appear [image: Missing file]
[image: Same here, missing]

I've checked all Stackoverflow answers also from other sources but most of them are similar and did't helped me. Really would appreciate who could help me to fix that, have been struggling with this for couple days. HELP!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072897/4977531 Shows you how to manually download the SDK and load it into Android Studio.

Comment: @Stanley Did  you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem. I have added the proxy and certificates.

Comment: @ponder275 yes, i just reinstalled the AS and was done

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to manualy set the sdk path:

[image]

Comment: yes,and that what i got: "Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation "

Comment: Normally the SDK comes with the android studio but during the installation setup you might have disabled some of the features that it requires. I would sudgest you delete the sdks that you have downloaded and reinstall android studio with the sdk that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

Download sdk from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)

1 open Settings >> A&B >> Android SDK

2 click on edit
[image]

3 open file explorer

[image]

4 select sdk folder

Comment: I did exactly like that. Downloaded SDK by myself, and tried to add it's path. And it says like this: "Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation ". And still no sdk tho